# Limit SQL columns to given range

Tags: mysql, sql

A column of datatype `integer` stores a value which a business rule requires must only be from 0 to 4194303.

How can the database enforce this rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases, you would use a `check` constraint.  MySQL allows you to declare check constraints but doesn't currently enforce them:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col check (col between 0 and 4194303);
```

(More specifically, none of the supported storage engines implement check constraints.)

Instead, you need to use a before insert and before update trigger to validate the value.  Perhaps future versions will actually enforce check constraints as well as allowing them to be declared.

If you are not familiar with triggers, you should not just copy code from Stack Overflow.  Instead, start by learning about them.  A good place to start is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html).

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  `check` was exactly what I was hoping for.  I added the trigger described in my edited post, however, it did not prevent a record with an `id` of 123 from being inserted.  Do you mind pointing out what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Never mind about my request to look at the trigger.  Works perfect.  Still would be nice to have `check` supported, but all is well.  Thanks again.